# Python 3 How to pull specific lines usin readlines from a file into an array

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if diff_choice == ("1"):
    with open(topic_pull + ".txt", "r") as ins:
        questionarray = []
        for line in ins:
            line = line.strip()
            questionarray.append(line)
```

How would I only pull several specific lines into the array (using something like `readlines()`)?

Thanks in advance

P.S. File looks like this:

Question

answ1

answ2

answ3

answ4

Question (etc, etc.)
If user wants 'easy' difficulty, it must read two answers from the file into the array. I already have code to make sure that the answers are not repeated into the array. What I want is for a `readlines()` fuction to read a random answer from each question and put it into the array.

Comment: Depends on which "specific lines" you want and what defines them as specific...

Comment: Ok but where is the correct answer of the 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list that includes wanted lines, try this:

```
wanted_lines = [1, 3]

with open("foo.txt", "r") as ins:
    questionarray = [line.strip() for count, line in enumerate(ins.readlines()) if count in wanted_lines]

print(questionarray)
```

Output:

```
['line2', 'line3']
```

**EDIT:**

You've accepted my answer but this can help to find wanted lines:

```
question_lines = [0, 5, 10]
wanted_lines = []

mode = "easy"
wanted_lines += question_lines
for line in question_lines:
    if(mode == "easy"):
        wanted_lines.append(line+1)
    elif(mode == "normal"):
        wanted_lines.append(line+2)
    elif(mode == "hard"):
        wanted_lines.append(line+3)
    else: # very hard
        wanted_lines.append(line+4)


with open("foo.txt", "r") as ins:
    result = [line.strip() for count, line in enumerate(ins.readlines()) if count in wanted_lines]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['Question1', 'answ1.1', 'Question2', 'answ2.1', 'Question3', 'answ3.1']
```

Answer (score 2):

**Updated answer**

Ok so the question was misinterpreted. You are asking to extract different lines based on index you know beforehand.

When you open a file you get an iterator back. You can read the first line to a variable and then continue reading the next lines to another by the example below:

---

**Example:**

In the example we stop reading after 6 lines.

```
string = """Question: Why?
Answer: Correct
Answer: Wrong 1
Answer: Wrong 2
Answer: Wrong 3
Question: Why?"""

with open("topic.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(string)

with open("topic.txt") as ins:
    # ins is now an iterator which you can extract info from
    question = ins.readline().strip() #Read first line
    answer = ins.readline().strip() #Read next
    wronganswers = [ins.readline().strip() for _ in range(3)] #Read next3
```

---

> question is now a string:  'Question: Why?'
>
> answer is now a string: 'Answer: Correct'
>
> wronganswers is now a list: ['...]

Comment: This does not work as I would like it to. If I print the array as you put it, nothing happens. If I put `ins.readlines(1)` then it prints out everything except for the first line, like this:          `line 2` `line 2, line 3` `line 2, line 3, line 4`

Comment: @UnusualKmc can you exemplify what your file looks like and the expected output?

Comment: Why use `readlines()` (which loads everything in memory) when you can directly iterate over the file ? `[i.strip() for i in ins if whatever]`

Comment: @AntonvBR My file contains questions and answers for a quiz. So the first line is the question, and the following few lines are answers. I have different difficulty levels. For example, 'easy' will print (in random order, by pulling from the array that I am trying to create) the correct answer and a random other answer. To do this I need to `readlines()` the correct answer and a random other answer.

Comment: @UnusualKmc I see what you want to do now. May I however suggest you share how the file looks like and I can provide you with a more efficient way to store the data (json).

Comment: @AntonvBR  Im sorry if Im explaining this in a complicated way. My file has 5 questions and 4 answers for each. If a user wants to play on easy mode, then my program prints the question and 2 possible answers (of which one is the guaranteed correct one.) To do this, I need some sort of `readlines()` into the array which will read the guaranteed answer from each question and a random other answer from the same question and put it into the array (in order).

Comment: @UnusualKmc I am glad to help but without you sharing your exact sample data it is hard to guess and modify after your needs. so you basically have 1 question 1 right answer 3 wrong answers and loop?

Comment: @AntonvBR Ive just realized how stupid ive been.. All I needed to do was write all the answers into separate arrays and then print from them. Thanks a ton for the help anyway